# VB6/VBA Declaration (Dim) Syntax Parser

Tags: c#, parsing, regex, meta-programming, rubberduck

As part of a project I'm working on, I've implemented a class that encapsulates the syntax for a [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)/[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) `Dim` statement.

Given a line of code, the `Parse` method uses a regular expression to match the keyword's syntax and extract the relevant parts.

As it stands there's no support for some valid syntaxes, the following aren't currently supported:

> ```
> 'multiple declarations on the same line:
> Dim foo As String, bar As String 
>
> 'multiple instructions on the same line:
> Dim foo As String: Dim bar As String
> ```

But this question isn't about the code that's not yet implemented, it's about the approach taken; the regular expression works (for the so-far supported use cases), but it's quickly going to become a problem (read: mess), especially since `DimSyntax` isn't going to be the only `ISyntax` implementation in the code.

On the other hand, [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6) isn't likely to ever change in the future, so perhaps a well-crafted regex can do the job, if it won't need to be maintained?

```cs
public class DimSyntax : ISyntax
{
    // todo: ditch regex
    private static readonly string _syntaxPattern = 
        @"^((?<keyword>Dim)\s(?<name>\w{1,30})\s?(As\s(?<type>\w{1,30})))?";

    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(_syntaxPattern);

    private readonly IVBTypeFactory _typeFactory;

    public DimSyntax(IVBTypeFactory typeFactory, IIdentifier identifier)
    {
        _typeFactory = typeFactory;
        _identifier = identifier;
    }

    private readonly IIdentifier _identifier;
    public IIdentifier Identifier { get { return _identifier; } }

    public string Keyword { get { return Keywords.Dim; } }

    public ISyntax Parse(string line)
    {
        var code = line.Trim();

        var match = _regex.Match(code);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var nameGroup = match.Groups["name"];
        var typeGroup = match.Groups["type"];
        if (nameGroup == null || typeGroup == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var type = _typeFactory.Parse(nameGroup.Value);
        var identifier = new Identifier(nameGroup.Value, type);

        return new DimSyntax(_typeFactory, identifier);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_identifier.Type != null)
        {
            // explicit type
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", Keyword, _identifier.Name, 
                                                  Keywords.As, _identifier.Type.TypeName);
        }
        else
        {
            // implicit type - Variant
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", Keyword, _identifier.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

`Keywords` is just a .resx resource file that contains a list of [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)/[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) keywords. I was going to make a `public static class` with a bunch of `public static readonly string` members, but I find it's cleaner to use a .resx file. Other suggestions?

I have mixed feelings about the `IVBTypeFactory` being a dependency of the *type*, when it's really a dependency of the `Parse` method - would it make sense to just take the abstract factory in as a method parameter instead?

---

For reference & context, here's the `Identifier` implementation:

```
public class Identifier : IIdentifier
{
    public Identifier(string name, IVBType type)
    {
        _name = name;
        _type = type;
    }

    private readonly string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }

    private readonly IVBType _type;
    public IVBType Type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

Pretty much all types are immutable, which means any number of threads can safely access the parsed `ISyntax` objects - am I making my life harder than it needs to be here?

If you need more context, or are curious to see more, the rest of the code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ckuhn203/VBEX/tree/master/VBEX).

Comment: Just realized, [I had the wrong definition for both parser and lexer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614928/1188513)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're actually going to need to parse more than just `Dim`s, I think the right solution is to use a parser generator like ANTLR. That way, the syntax is going to be more readable than a bunch of overcomplicated regexes, the code is going to be more DRY (because you won't need to write all the group-extraction code) and the result is going to be a proper syntax tree.

Comment: Yup. Ended up using ANTLR, works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Finally, a question where we can use Roslyn!

I won't review your own code but instead I whipped up this small showcase of how you might do it with the Roslyn compilers. Do note that it is rather ugly, not in the least because I am not entirely comfortable with it myself yet but also because I know little VB.NET and it appears some things are handled differently from the C# compiler. That being said, this sample implementation can parse both

```
Dim foo As String
```

and

```
Dim foo As String, bar As String
```

El codos:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stuffIWantToParse = "Dim foo As String, bar As String";

        var tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
            Module Module1
                 " + stuffIWantToParse +
            @" End Module
        ");

        var compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree });
        var moduleType = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("Module1");

        PrintVariableDeclarationByIndex(0, moduleType);
        PrintVariableDeclarationByIndex(1, moduleType);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void PrintVariableDeclarationByIndex(int i, INamedTypeSymbol moduleType)
    {
        var variable = moduleType.GetMembers().Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();

        var position = variable.Locations.First().SourceSpan.Start;
        var root = variable.Locations.First().SourceTree.GetRoot();
        var parent = root.FindToken(position).Parent;
        var node = parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf<FieldDeclarationSyntax>();
        var typeInfo = node.Declarators[i].AsClause;

        Console.WriteLine("Modifiers: " + string.Join(",", node.Modifiers));
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + variable.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + typeInfo.Type());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Using a workaround from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428662/how-to-find-the-syntaxnode-for-a-method-symbol-in-a-compilationunit). If you want some more codesamples on Roslyn, look at my project [here](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics). In order to use the Visual Basic compilers look [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic/0.7.4052301-beta). For more information on Roslyn, take a look at the [roslyn](/questions/tagged/roslyn) tag wiki I put together.

Comment: That's... rather interesting! Does `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic` work with VB6/VBA or just VB.NET?

Comment: Aww.. It's just for VB.NET I believe. Are there difference between the `As` statements between these versions?

Comment: Well *in theory* VB6 *could be* parsed as VB.NET (I *think*), ..it might be worth a serious shot.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing something in your object model.
Consider this snippet that creates the regex pattern.

```
private static readonly string _syntaxPattern = 
    @"^((?<keyword>Dim)\s(?<name>\w{1,30})\s?(As\s(?<type>\w{1,30})))?";
```

And this snippet that defines the keyword for the class.

```
public string Keyword { get { return Keywords.Dim; } }
```

If you stick with the regex to do this, you'll find that you can use an almost identical pattern for several `ISyntax` implementations. For a hypothetical `PublicSyntax` you would have this:

```
private static readonly string _syntaxPattern = 
    @"^((?<keyword>Public)\s(?<name>\w{1,30})\s?(As\s(?<type>\w{1,30})))?";
```

and

```
public string Keyword { get { return Keywords.Public; } }
```

This tells me that both of those need to inherit a `GetSyntaxPattern()` function that returns something like this.

```
protected virtual string GetSyntaxPattern()
{
    return "^((?" + this.Keyword + ")\s(?<name>\w{1,30})\s?(As\s(?<type>\w{1,30})))?";
}
```

Or perhaps it would be even better as a property.

```
protected virtual string SyntaxPattern()
{
    get { return "^((?" + this.Keyword + ")\s(?<name>\w{1,30})\s?(As\s(?<type>\w{1,30})))?"; }
}
```