# I think I might be having a regex nightmare

Tags: c#, parsing, regex, rubberduck

I've been working on the [Rubberduck](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck) (an add-in for the VBA Editor /"VBE"), specifically here the `VBA.Parser` namespace. Here's how I ended up implementing the syntax part.

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public interface ISyntax
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses an instruction into a syntax node, if possible.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="publicScope">The fully-qualified scope of the specified instruction, when the instruction is publicly scoped.</param>.
    /// <param name="localScope">The fully-qualified scope of the specified instruction, when the instruction is locally scoped.</param>
    /// <param name="instruction">An instruction.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns a node representing the specified instruction, 
    /// or <c>null</c> if specified instruction can't be parsed.
    /// </returns>
    SyntaxTreeNode Parse(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction);

    bool IsMatch(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction, out SyntaxTreeNode node);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether syntax is specific to a particular parent node.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Implementations with this member set to <c>true</c> will not be considered as part of the general grammar.
    /// </remarks>
    bool IsChildNodeSyntax { get; }

    SyntaxType Type { get; }
}
```

Now, armed with this... thing:

> **WARNING**
>
> **Faint of heart, beware.** The mere sight of these regex patterns is known to have caused nausea in at least, uh, one, somewhat documented case.

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public static class VBAGrammar
{
    private static string IdentifierSyntax { get { return @"(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))"; } }
    private static string ReferenceSyntax { get { return @"(?:(?<reference>(?:(?:(?<library>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\.)*)?" + IdentifierSyntax + ")"; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all implementations of <see cref="SyntaxBase"/> in the Rubberduck assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<ISyntax> GetGrammarSyntax()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                           .GetTypes()
                           .Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(SyntaxBase))
                           .Select(type =>
                           {
                               var constructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                               return constructorInfo != null ? constructorInfo.Invoke(Type.EmptyTypes) : null;
                           })
                           .Cast<ISyntax>()
                           .ToList();
    }

    public static string IdentifierDeclarationSyntax
    {
        get
        {
            return "(?<declarations>(?:" + IdentifierSyntax +
                   @"(?<specifier>[%&@!#$])?(?<array>\((?<size>(([0-9]+)\,?\s?)*|([0-9]+\sTo\s[0-9]+\,?\s?)+)\))?(?<as>\sAs(\s(?<initializer>New))?\s" +
                   ReferenceSyntax + @")?)(?:\,\s)?)+";
        }
    }

    public static string DeclarationKeywordsSyntax
    {
        get
        {
            return @"^(?:(?:(?<keywords>(?:(?:(?<accessibility>Private|Public|Global)\s)|(?<accessibility>Private|Public|Global)\s)?(?:(?<keyword>WithEvents|Private|Public|Friend|Global|Dim|Const|Static|Sub|Function|Property\sGet|Property\sLet|Property\sSet|Enum|Type|Declare\sFunction)))\s)?)";
        }
    }

    public static string GeneralDeclarationSyntax
    {
        get { return DeclarationKeywordsSyntax + "(?<expression>.*)?"; }
    }

    public static string LabelSyntax
    {
        get { return @"^(?<identifier>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\:$"; }
    }

    public static string EnumSyntax
    {
        get { return @"^((?<accessibility>Private|Public|Global)\s)?Enum\s" + IdentifierSyntax; }
    }


    public static string EnumMemberSyntax
    {
        get { return @"^" + IdentifierSyntax + @"(\s\=\s(?<value>.*))?$"; }
    }

    public static string UserDefinedTypeSyntax
    {
        get { return @"^(?:(?<accessibility>Private|Public|Global)\s)?Type\s" + IdentifierSyntax; }
    }

    public static string ProcedureSyntax
    {
        get
        {
            return
                @"(?:(?<accessibility>Friend|Private|Public)\s)?(?:(?<kind>Sub|Function|Property\s(Get|Let|Set)))\s(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))\((?<parameters>(?:\(\)|[^()])*)?\)(?:\sAs\s(?<reference>(((?<library>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\.)?(?<identifier1>([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))(?<array>\(\))?)?";
        }
    }

    public static string ParameterSyntax
    {
        get
        {
            var identifierPart =IdentifierSyntax + @"(?<specifier>[%&@!#$])?(?<array>\((?<size>(([0-9]+)\,?\s?)*|([0-9]+\sTo\s[0-9]+\,?\s?)+)\))?(?<as>\sAs\s" + ReferenceSyntax + @")?";

            var syntax = @"(?<parameter>(?:((?<optional>Optional)\s)?(?<by>ByRef|ByVal|ParamArray)?\s?)*"
                + identifierPart + @")";


            return syntax;
        }
    }

    public static string IfBlockSyntax
    {
        get { return @"(?<!End\s)(?:If|Else|ElseIf?\s)(?<condition>.*)\sThen(?:\s(?<expression>.*))?"; }
    }

    public static string ForLoopSyntax
    {
        get { return @"For\s" + IdentifierSyntax + @"\s=\s(?<lower>.*)\sTo\s(?<upper>.*)(?:\sStep\s(?<step>.*))?"; }
    }

    public static string ForEachLoopSyntax
    {
        get { return @"For\sEach\s" + IdentifierSyntax + @"\sIn\s(?<expression>.*)"; }
    }

    public static string DoLoopSyntax
    {
        get { return @"(?:(?<keyword>Do|Loop|Do\sLoop|Do\sUnTil|Do\sWhile|While)\s)(?<expression>.*)?"; }
    }

    public static string TypeConversionSyntax
    {
        get { return @"(?<keyword>CBool|CByte|CCur|CDate|CDbl|CInt|CLng|CSng|CStr|CVar)\((?<expression>.*)\)"; }
    }

    public static string OptionSyntax
    {
        get { return @"Option\s(?<option>:Base|Compare|Explicit|Private\sModule)(?:\s(?<value>)0|1|Binary|Text|Database)?"; }
    }

    public static string AssignmentSyntax
    {
        get { return ReferenceSyntax + @"\s=\s(?<expression>.*)"; }
    }
}
```

I could implement `ISyntax` like this:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public abstract class SyntaxBase : ISyntax
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    protected SyntaxBase(SyntaxType syntaxType = SyntaxType.Syntax)
    {
        _syntaxType = syntaxType;
    }

    protected abstract bool MatchesSyntax(string instruction, out Match match);
    protected abstract SyntaxTreeNode CreateNode(Instruction instruction, string scope, Match match);

    protected virtual string Scope(string publicScope, string localScope, Match match)
    {
        var publicScopeKeywords = new[] { 
                                            ReservedKeywords.Public, 
                                            ReservedKeywords.Global 
                                        };

        return publicScopeKeywords.Contains(match.Value.Split(' ')[0] + ' ')
                                    ? publicScope
                                    : localScope;
    }

    private readonly SyntaxType _syntaxType;
    public SyntaxType Type { get { return _syntaxType; } }

    public virtual SyntaxTreeNode Parse(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction)
    {
        Match match;
        if (!MatchesSyntax(instruction.Value.Trim(), out match))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var scope = Scope(publicScope, localScope, match);
     
        return CreateNode(instruction, scope, match);
    }

    public bool IsMatch(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction, out SyntaxTreeNode node)
    {
        node = Parse(publicScope, localScope, instruction);
        return node != null;
    }


    public bool IsChildNodeSyntax
    {
        get { return _syntaxType.HasFlag(SyntaxType.IsChildNodeSyntax); }
    }
}
```

And derive from this base class anytime I want to extend/refine the parsing with a new syntax:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class OptionSyntax : SyntaxBase
{
    protected override bool MatchesSyntax(string instruction, out Match match)
    {
        match = Regex.Match(instruction, VBAGrammar.OptionSyntax);
        return match.Success;
    }

    protected override SyntaxTreeNode CreateNode(Instruction instruction, string scope, Match match)
    {
        return new OptionNode(instruction, scope, match);
    }
}
```

When I extend the syntax, I also create a new `SyntaxTreeNode` implementation:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ParameterNode : SyntaxTreeNode
{
    public ParameterNode(Instruction instruction, string scope, Match match)
        : base(instruction, scope, match, new[] {new IdentifierNode(instruction, scope, match)})
    {
        _isImplicitByRef = !match.Groups["by"].Success;
    }

    public IdentifierNode Identifier { get { return ChildNodes.OfType<IdentifierNode>().Single(); } }

    private readonly bool _isImplicitByRef;
    public bool IsImplicitByRef { get { return _isImplicitByRef; } }
}
```

---

This regex-based strategy [has backfired already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27477824/1188513), so I'm wondering if my approach makes sense... or if I've completely set myself up for a regex maintenance nightmare...

I'm using Expresso to compose and test and debug these regular expressions. But.. they're nasty nonetheless, aren't they?

Comment: [Do NOT use too many regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Caridorc I'm using *regular expressions* to parse *regular syntax* here - nothing to do with parsing XML or HTML. Zalgo can't get me ;) ...well I hope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Regex-nightmare**

By looking at the returned value of `IdentifierDeclarationSyntax`

```
(?<declarations>(?:(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))(?<specifier>[%&@!#$])?(?<array>\((?<size>(([0-9]+)\,?\s?)*|([0-9]+\sTo\s[0-9]+\,?\s?)+)\))?(?<as>\sAs(\s(?<initializer>New))?\s(?:(?<reference>(?:(?:(?<library>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\.)*)?(?<identifier>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]))))?)(?:\,\s)?)+
```

and the fact that you couldn't make it fool proof in at least 6 months ([oldest question I have found](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/53800/29371)), I would say yes you have a nightmare. If you have a bug, debugging this won't be fun.

**General**

- here you don't need a `readonly bool`, you should use an auto property with a `private` setter

  ```
  [ComVisible(false)]
  public class ParameterNode : SyntaxTreeNode
  {
      public ParameterNode(Instruction instruction, string scope, Match match)
      : base(instruction, scope, match, new[] {new IdentifierNode(instruction, scope, match)})
      {
          IsImplicitByRef = !match.Groups["by"].Success;
      }

      public IdentifierNode Identifier { get { return ChildNodes.OfType<IdentifierNode>().Single(); } }

      public bool IsImplicitByRef { get; private set; }
  }
  ```

  This also applies to `SyntaxBase.Type` and `SyntaxBase.IsChildNodeSyntax`
- In the `VBAGrammar.GetGrammarSyntax()` you are calling unnecessary `.ToList()`.
- Empty xml documentation should be removed.

Answer (score 6):

`ISyntax` boils down to this:

```
public interface ISyntax
{
    SyntaxTreeNode Parse(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction);
    bool IsMatch(string publicScope, string localScope, Instruction instruction, out SyntaxTreeNode node);
    bool IsChildNodeSyntax { get; }
    SyntaxType Type { get; }
}
```

Which does not, in any way, *force* you to implement `IsMatch` with regular expressions. It's deriving from `SyntaxBase` that does, and the fact that the only implementations of `ISyntax` your parser is looking at, all derive from `SyntaxBase`:

```
public static IEnumerable<ISyntax> GetGrammarSyntax()
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                       .GetTypes()
                       .Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(SyntaxBase))
                       .Select(type =>
                       {
                           var constructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                           return constructorInfo != null ? constructorInfo.Invoke(Type.EmptyTypes) : null;
                       })
                       .Cast<ISyntax>()
                       .ToList();
}
```

This little reflection trick clearly doesn't belong in the `VBAGrammar` static class. You haven't provided enough context for anyone to recommend where it should be, but looking at the code on GitHub it seems the `App` class is doing the same thing... so `VBAGrammar.GetGrammarSyntax` could probably be removed altogether, and you should be selecting all types that directly or indirectly implement `ISyntax`, not just types derived from `SyntaxBase`.

Doing that will enable you to implement `ISyntax` without involving any regular expressions - and even to re-implement the currently regex-based ones with plain C# code, should the regex patterns turn out being problematic or inefficient at one point or another.

Another thing that's tying the parsing to regular expressions, is the fact that a `SyntaxTreeNode` implementation "requires" a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` instance - I don't think it's needed. Expose setters for the properties (like `IsImplicitByRef`), and let the individual properties be set by the `ISyntax` implementation that creates that node, instead of accessing an encapsulated `Match` object.

That said I like how `SyntaxBase` makes extending the parser as "easy" as coming up with a regular expression to capture it; I find it's a good design *when you **do** need a regex* - but you probably don't **need** a regex for all syntaxes (e.g. `OptionSyntax` looks like it could very well be implemented with regular string-handling methods, in plain code), and I'm not convinced you need the `VBAGrammar` static class at all: each `ISyntax` implementation that needs a regex pattern could have it as a private field.